# concat two files side-by-side, append difference between fields, and print in tabular format

Tags: bash, awk

Consider I have a two files as below: I need to concatenate and find difference in the new file.

a.txt

```
a 2019 66
b 2020 50
c 2018 48
```

b.txt

```
a 2019 50
b 2019 40
c 2018 45
```

Desired output:

```
a 2019 66 a 2019 50 16
b 2020 50 b 2019 40 10
c 2018 48 c 2018 45 3
```

I tried:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=" " '{$7=$3-$6}1' file3.txt
```

it prints

```
a 2019 66 a 2019 50 0
b 2020 50 b 2019 40 0
c 2018 48 c 2018 45 0
```

Also can help in printing in tabular format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your awk command seems fine except `-F,`. You should `paste` those files first.

```
$ paste a.txt b.txt | awk '{print $0,$3-$6}' | column -t
a  2019  66  a  2019  50  16
b  2020  50  b  2019  40  10
c  2018  48  c  2018  45  3
```

Comment: Also can you help me to print in tabular format in unix? please

Comment: how and where to use -t?

Comment: thanks. i want the desired output in a tabular format so that i can send that in email

Comment: how to tweak awk cmd to do diff on two columns , consider 2020-2019 and 50 -40

Comment: i need to difference bw 2 columns? as said above. can you pls help

Answer (score 2):

Within single `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;b[FNR]=$NF;next} {print a[FNR],$0,b[FNR]-$NF}' a.txt b.txt | column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
a  2019  66  a  2019  50  16
b  2020  50  b  2019  40  10
c  2018  48  c  2018  45  3
```